# Не получается десериализовать JSON строку

Tags: c#, json

Вообщем есть JSON строка:

```
{
    "38938719": [
        {
            "tier": "DIAMOND",
            "queue": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
            "name": "Varus's Army",
            "entries": [
                {
                    "isFreshBlood": false,
                    "division": "V",
                    "isVeteran": false,
                    "wins": 73,
                    "losses": 68,
                    "playerOrTeamId": "38938719",
                    "playerOrTeamName": "ShironekoSistine",
                    "isInactive": false,
                    "isHotStreak": true,
                    "leaguePoints": 37
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "tier": "DIAMOND",
            "queue": "RANKED_FLEX_SR",
            "name": "Sejuani's Highwaymen",
            "entries": [
                {
                    "isFreshBlood": false,
                    "division": "III",
                    "isVeteran": false,
                    "wins": 38,
                    "losses": 26,
                    "playerOrTeamId": "38938719",
                    "playerOrTeamName": "ShironekoSistine",
                    "isInactive": false,
                    "isHotStreak": false,
                    "leaguePoints": 3
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

И я создал классы для ее десириализации

```
 public class Entry
    {
        public string playerOrTeamId { get; set; }
        public string playerOrTeamName { get; set; }
        public string division { get; set; }
        public int leaguePoints { get; set; }
        public int wins { get; set; }
        public int losses { get; set; }
        public bool isHotStreak { get; set; }
        public bool isVeteran { get; set; }
        public bool isFreshBlood { get; set; }
        public bool isInactive { get; set; }
    }

    public class __invalid_type__38938719
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string tier { get; set; }
        public string queue { get; set; }
        public List<Entry> entries { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<__invalid_type__38938719> __invalid_name__38938719 { get; set; }
    }
```

Делал методом `RootObject summonerInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(answer);`
где `answer` - полученная JSON строка в формате string
но ошибка в том, вечно получается что даже `__invalid_name__38938719` Принимает значение `null` во время работы программы, ну и соответственно все остальные значения тоже.
Что я делаю не так? уже целый день сижу над этим...

Answer (score 2):

С помощью чего вы генерили модели? Что это `__invalid_type__38938719`? Больше не используйте эту шляпу.

Для представления ассоциативных массивов используется класс `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

Использование:

```
var resultObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, List<Element>>>(jsonString);
```

[Тестить](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0BETEc)!

Ваши модели:

```
public class Entry
{
    public string PlayerOrTeamId { get; set; }
    public string PlayerOrTeamName { get; set; }
    public string Division { get; set; }
    public int LeaguePoints { get; set; }
    public int Wins { get; set; }
    public int Losses { get; set; }
    public bool IsHotStreak { get; set; }
    public bool IsVeteran { get; set; }
    public bool IsFreshBlood { get; set; }
    public bool IsInactive { get; set; }
}

public class Element
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Tier { get; set; }
    public string Queue { get; set; }
    public List<Entry> Entries { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Это очень похоже на стандартный генератор visual студии который в меню Edit -> Paste special